# Modifying calendar library to restrict length by number of days

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to use the built in Codeigniter calendar library to create a calendar with the 40 next days. I would like each month to be displayed as a normal calendar placed horizontally by each other. In other words, there should be 2-3 calendars horizontally aligned.

Any good tip where I should start?

Answer (score 0):

create your own user control. using calender control

hope this will give you a clue to proceed

Comment: I tried searching around a bit, but wasn't able to find out what you mean by "user control"... Would you mind giving some extra clues? :P